# Is a generic return value that "extends" an interface equal to just the interface as an returnvalue?

Tags: java, generics

The question might be a bit confusing. What I'm really interested in is the following.

Is this:

```
<T extends SomeInterface > T method() {
    ...
}
```

equivalent to this:

```
SomeInterface method() {
    ...
}
```

To me, it both seems to serve the same purpose, but then I ask myself why you can write the first, longer one, at all.

##### My thought

Both implementations suggest, that something that implements SomeInterface gets returned. Both can be further specified in subclasses.

Comment: No, learn about generics and you'll see there are many differences.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Assuming that `SubClass extends SomeClass`: is `SubClass method()` the same as `SomeClass method()` ? Can you write `SubClass test = method()` if the method is declared as `SomeClass method()`?

Comment: Well the generic parameter binds `T` to the actual type, whereas with `SomeObject` it'll always be of type `SomeObject` even if you're dealing with `SomeSubObject`. I recommend a long read about generics, because it's a complicated subject and just picking up single examples like this will be a really slow way to learn.

Comment: In the first version, I can call `method` and get back an instance of the implementation (T) that I want. In the second, `method` can return any implementation _it_ wants.

Answer (score 0):

They are very different. In the second declaration, `SomeInterface method()`, the method can return an instance of any subclass of `SomeInterface` it wants, and the caller cannot expect any particular subclass except that it is a subtype of `SomeInterface`. The caller can only safely assign the result to type `SomeInterface`.

In the first declaration, `<T extends SomeInterface> T method()`, the caller can get back whatever subclass type it wants. Suppose `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` are both subtypes of `SomeInterface`. The method being a generic method means that it promises to work no matter what `T` is. So one caller can want `T` to be `SubClassA`, and do `SubClassA a = method();`. And another caller can want `T` to be `SubClassB`, and do `SubClassB b = method();`. The method `method()`'s declaration guarantees that this will always work and be safe, without `method` knowing what `T` is. But since `method()` doesn't take any arguments, how does it know what `T` the caller wants? It can't. There is no way to safely implement this method unless it always returns `null`.